# Which Office JS functions work differently on the Mac Excel client?

Tags: excel, macos, office-js

My Excel add-in works perfectly fine in Excel client for Windows, Excel Web on a Windows browser and Excel Web on a Mac browser. However, it fails with a "GeneralException" in the Excel client for Mac. My add-in only uses the published Office API functions + JQuery and does not use the file system or any other external services.

Isn't the Office-js api cross-platform? Are there any functions that work differently? My add-in failure seems to occur when it adds named ranges and validations. Because it works fine when I run it on the browser, I can't even debug this further. If you have encountered a similar issue and/or have a solution, I'd appreciate hearing from you.

Comment: I've had a harder time getting add-ins to work on Windows than Mac since IE11 is so quirky.

Comment: Brutal honesty: If you're going to develop for a system, you need to test on that system. Mac and Windows are very different "under the covers". The Office applications needed to make some massive adjustments to be able to run on Mac and some things are just... different.

Comment: Please also take a moment to review the site's guidelines for asking questions. Asking people to "share their experiences" does not fit the Q&A format. As stated, this contribution is "too broad" / needs more focus.

Comment: @Cindy -- thanks for your brutal honesty. As a long time developer, I realize that too. However...when you build something with a cross-platform API using basic API functionality, should you need to test on every platform it could possibly run on? Even if that is not your target platform? I think not. I think it is a failure of the API if that is so. I'm sure I'm not the first one having this issue and soliciting others to share "gotchas" would be helpful to me and future readers.

Comment: @Cindy -- updated question as per your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it looks like a bug in the Excel client for Mac that is getting no love or attention from Microsoft. To circumvent it, I had to resort to conditionally removing the feature with something like this:

```
     if (Office.context.platform === Office.PlatformType.Mac) {
        console.log("Yep, I'm on the darn mac client");
        //disable feature...
```

Answer (score -1):

All the released Excel JS APIs are cross-platform. If you see a difference in behavior, please send the sample scripts that can reproduce the problem, and we can investigate that caused that. Thanks.

Comment: By "sample scripts", do you mean the add-in manifest or something else?

Comment: I mean the scripts that can be used to reproduce the issue. We need to narrow down which API all, or what operation caused the General exception.

Comment: Error can be reproduced by: 1. download and install add-in from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rulescape/odm-test-lynx-samples/master/RuleScapeODMTestBuddyManifest.xml) 2. Download and open sample excel data file from [here](https://github.com/rulescape/odm-test-lynx-samples/blob/master/rulescape%20odm%20test%20sample%20-%20after.xlsx) 3. Launch add-in pane from Data->'Enhance ODM Tests' 4. Click 'Apply Selected Options'.

Comment: This error occurs only on Excel client for Mac. No error occurs when running this on Excel Web on Mac/Safari, Excel Web on Windows browser or Excel on Windows. Is this sufficient to characterize this issue as an **Excel API bug** on Mac and thereby give it the attention it deserves?